# Join or Union All To Combine Records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 similar tables that contain campaign names.  I know I can do an union all to combine the tables, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this using form of Join instead? I want to create a table Z with campaign names for table A plus campaign names from table B (which are not in A).  Can I do this with a join or is Union ALL the only way?

Comment: If you provide us with your table schemas we can probably help.  Otherwise we'd be guessing.

Comment: Note that `UNION ALL` will not get you "campaign names for table A plus campaign names from table B (which are not in A)". The not in A part will not be handled by the `UNION ALL`. If you only want distinct values you need `UNION`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNION is the easier and correct way to do that. Purely for the exercise you can do it with a JOIN but it is a lot more complex, unreadable, and the perf will be way worse...

Comment: That makes sense.  I understand the second answer works as well, but I was wondering design-wise, which was the more viable option.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * INTO TABLEZ
FROM 
  (
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3.... FROM TABLEA 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3.... FROM TABLEB
  )Q
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do this with a `full outer join`:

```
select distinct coalesce(a.campaign, b.campaign)
from b left outer join
     a
     on a.campaign = b.campaign;
```

The `union`/`union all` approach is totally reasonable.  I'm just offering this as a `join` solution that you seem to be alluding to in the question.